# How to get a List composed of Hyperlinks onto an excel or word file?

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink, web, app-store

So I want to get these Top Ranking lists from the website App Annie which recording ranking information from the itunes App Store on to a standard excel file.

Here is the link: http://www.appannie.com/top/

Each app listed on the Top Paid, Top Free, Top Grossing are all linked to the apps details page. I essentially want to get these top 100 lists on a excel file. I do not want to manually type in the day by day rankings.

But I have no idea how this could be done.

Also if anyone knows a source that simply provides an excel file with the daily App Store rankings that would be even better.

Thank You.

Comment: The task you want to perform is called "web scraping" or "screen scraping". Since you haven't nominated a programming language or tool you prefer, I can't help you much further - but at least you now know what words to Google for. ;)

Comment: And with those very keywords and Stackoverflow, you should be able to find something very close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck pasting from the page as a refreshable web query.

In Excel 2010: Go to Paste > Refreshable Web Query. In the window that pops up, load your desired website, and then click the arrow in the top left in order to select the whole page. Then click import.

The resulting paste isn't exactly pretty, but once you remove the garbage from the top and the bottom you have a fairly workable result.